# Can't save a document to mongodb with mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have my schema as this

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
    uid : {type: String, required: true},
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    description: {type: String, required: true}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', schema)
```

In another file, I include this file, and try to seed the db:

```
var Task = require('../models/task');
var uuid4 = require('uuid4')
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/app', {useNewUrlParser: true});
var task = new Task({
    uid: uuid4(),
    title: 'task3 name',
    description: 'task3 desc'
})
task.save(function (err) {
     if (err) console.log(err)
  })
}
```

No matter what I do, it won't save the data I want.
Now, when I dive into the db, app database, tasks collection, there are no inserts over there

version: "mongoose": "^5.5.2",

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, everything is clear

Comment: Have you tried putting your schema in the same file that makes the connection? Most likely the require('mongoose') in your schema file and your seed file are not sharing the same scope, so you're calling save on a model that has no connection.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. No difference

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#constructing-documents)

> If you create a custom connection, use that connection's model() function instead.

```
var connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
var Tank = connection.model('Tank', yourSchema);
```

So you need to declare your model from your connection so that it knows which connection to associate the `.save()` action.

I would recommend creating a dedicated `db.js` file that handles creating the connection which can then be imported into each of your schema files in order to create the model from the supplied connection.